# Calculate date and time in two separate records

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Can anyone please help me. I am trying to calculate the difference between record entry 1 and record entry 2 and so and so on date and time in two separate records

[image: Image Example]

I want to add another row to calculate the difference Between Entry 1 and Entry 2. I know that if i did have a check in and check out then i could just subtract time out from time in and its sorted. But have never tried between records

Update And the Code that i'm using is:

```
   SELECT USERINFO.name, CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME
   FROM CHECKINOUT, USERINFO
   WHERE (((USERINFO.name)=[Enter Name]))
   ORDER BY CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
name,
DateValue(CHECKTIME) AS Date,
TimeValue(CHECKTIME) AS Time
From CHECKOUT
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be:

```
Select *,
    (CheckTime - (Select Top 1 CheckTime 
    From [Employee Check] As T 
    Where T.Name = [Employee Check].Name 
        And T.CheckTime < [Employee Check].CheckTime
    Order By T.CheckTime Desc)) As CheckTimeDiff
From [Employee Check]
```

Comment: The current code I'm using is:SELECT USERINFO.name, CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME
FROM CHECKINOUT, USERINFO
WHERE (((USERINFO.name)=[Enter Name]))
ORDER BY CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME DESC;

Comment: And that you have saved as _Employee Check_, so it seems.

Comment: Yip that is correct. But Still getting an error saying "Circular reference caused by "Employee Check""

Comment: Sounds like you've forgotten an alias.

Comment: Been going though it over and over again. Think i'm missing something.